# lastlog command output contains duplicate lines

Tags: login, 20.04

AFAIK, until yesterday the output of the `lastlog` command contained unique lines for each user. Today I see two identical lines for `root` and `nobody`:

```
# lastlog
Username         Port     From             Latest
root             pts/1    10.0.0.9         Wed Jul  8 18:32:10 +0300 2020
[...]
nobody                                     **Never logged in**
[...]
root             pts/1    10.0.0.9         Wed Jul  8 18:32:10 +0300 2020
nobody                                     **Never logged in**
```

I tried:

```
# lastlog -C -u root
```

and now the output is the same, except the login information for `root` being cleared:

```
# lastlog
Username         Port     From             Latest
root                                       **Never logged in**
[...]
nobody                                     **Never logged in**
[...]
root                                       **Never logged in**
nobody                                     **Never logged in**
```

Why do I have duplicates in `lastlog`'s output?